# REST api: search on two specific resources and return in single response

Tags: rest, api

I have two resources, let us call them `animal` and `human`.

I have a search that can get me any `animal` where `name=bob` and the same for `human`

What I would prefer is one API route that searches on both resources. I do however have other resources in my schema that might have their own search in the future so I cannot just call this `search`.

I was thinking of something like `GET:/animal-human-search` but is that pretty and consistent with the correct way of doing things

Any ideas?